# How to get the median value from a CSV column in AWK? (linux)

Tags: linux, awk, gnu

I would like to catch the median value from second column of this CSV file grouped by Continent in a script awk file:

```
Continent, Ratio
Asia,4.313743132
Europe,1.275057509
Africa,2.587215976
Europe,0.382270638
Africa,1.915438434
Latin America and the Caribbean,1.801681569
Latin America and the Caribbean,1.416472111
Asia,2.039169471
Latin America and the Caribbean,0.622595518
```

I tried but it doesn't work because I didn't sort CSV and I didn't even group by continent:

```
BEGIN {
    FS = ","
    Continent["Africa"];Continent["Asia"];Continent["Europe"];Continent["Latin America and the Caribbean"];
}
FNR>1 {
    if ($1!="" && $2!="") {
        a[i++]=$2
}


}END {
    for (i in Continent) {
        x=int((i+1)/2); if (x < (i+1)/2) print (a[x-1]+a[x])/2; else print a[x-1];
     }
}
```

How ever, I expect to order first of all the csv by Continent and Numeric (desc or asc, doesn't matter):

```
Continent, Ratio
Africa,2.587215976
Africa,1.915438434
Asia,4.313743132
Asia,2.039169471
Europe,1.275057509
Europe,0.382270638
Latin America and the Caribbean,1.801681569
Latin America and the Caribbean,1.416472111
Latin America and the Caribbean,0.622595518
```

And finally getting the median by Continent:

```
Continent, Median
Africa 2,2513
Asia   3,1764
Europe 0,8286
Latin America and the Caribbean, 1.4164
```

Comment: How large is the CSV? (ie. does it easily fit in memory?

Comment: 246 rows in total, yep, easily fit in memory!

Comment: Does your file have a header line? You don't show one but that `FNR>1` suggests there is one.

Comment: Totally, you're right. Yes, there is! Updated.

Comment: Or using [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/) (Disclaimer: I'm a contributor): `datamash -H -s -t, groupby 1 median 2 < file.csv`

Comment: How's this a dupe when OP's data is not in correct order?

Comment: @anubhava The answer in the linked q&a sorts input (OP will need to adjust it to sort the first column alphabetically instead of numerically, as well as fix the usage of `", "` as input and output delimiters)

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, I think there are few differences and it is something that can be done in a single command instead of two.

Comment: @anubhava Add an answer to that question, then.

Comment: IMO that question should be closed for showing no attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun, you could write this in a single `gawk` script, but in coordination with `sort`, using a [two-way pipe (or coprocess)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html):

###### median.awk

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f

function median(values, _, len) {
  len = length(values)

  if (len % 2 == 1) {
    return values[(len + 1) / 2]
  } else {
    return (values[int(len / 2)] + values[int(len / 2) + 1]) / 2
  }
}

BEGIN {
  # Set (Input) Field and Output Field Separators.
  FS = OFS = ","

  # The `sort` process to which we'll send data.
  #
  # -t,    → set comma (,) to be the input separator
  # -k1,1  → 1st sort key starts at the 1st field and ends at the 1st field
  # -k2,2n → 2nd sort key starts at the 2nd field and ends at the 2nd field
  #          and use numeric comparisons.
  sorted = "LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k1,1 -k2,2n"
}

NR == 1 {
  next # skip first line
}

{
  # Pipe incoming lines to a sorting coprocess.
  # See: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Two_002dway-I_002fO.html
  print $0 |& sorted
}

END {
  # Close the writing end of the `sorted` pipe.
  close(sorted, "to")

  while (1) {
    # Read sorted data.
    more = sorted |& getline

    # Print median when there's no more data or when we're switching between regions.
    if (!more || (region && region != $1)) {
      print region, sprintf("%.6f", median(vals))
      vals_i = 0
      delete vals
    }

    # Clean up when there's no more data.
    if (!more) {
      close(sorted)
      break
    }

    region = $1
    vals[++vals_i] = $2
  }
}
```

#### Result

```
$ ./median.awk data.txt 
Africa,2.251327
Asia,3.176456
Europe,0.828664
Latin America and the Caribbean,1.416472
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gnu-awk` you may use this solution:

```bash
cat med.awk

function med(d) {
   return gensub(/\./, ",", "1", sprintf("%.4f",
      (n%2 ? d[(n+1)/2] : (d[n/2] + d[n/2+1]) / 2)))
}
BEGIN {
   FS = ","
   OFS = "\t"
}
NR > 1 {
   a[$0] = $2
}
END {
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"   # this is for sorting
   print "Continent", "Median
   for (i in a) {
      k = gensub(/,.*/, "", "1", i)
      if (k != pk) {
         if (pk)
            print pk, med(d)
         n = 0
         delete d
      }
      d[++n] = a[i]
      pk = k
   }
   print pk, med(d)
}
```

Then use it as:

```bash
awk -f med.awk file | column -t -s $'\t'

Continent                        Median
Africa                           2,2513
Asia                             3,1765
Europe                           0,8287
Latin America and the Caribbean  1,4165
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava, success! The key is gensub function, among other things, I didn't meet before! Bravo!

Comment: Hmm surprised that single awk solution wasn't good enough as compared to a solution that calls external `sort` utility.